# How can I test the performance of my website after the initial load?

Tags: performance, web-applications, load-testing, performance-testing, web-testing

I have created a website that allows users to search a database. It is a Perl script that searches oracle using Perl DBI then writes in HTML and JavaScript.
I have found many websites that will quantitatively test the initial loading of the website. I can't help but think that the figures I have are false because the test is not actually performing a search and loading any data.

Are there any tools for testing the speed and performance of the interactive operations of a site beyond its initial load?

Answer (score 0):

You can look to wiring up load testing with something like WebDriver and JMeter. Lots of folks use these or similar tools for just these sorts of scenarios. They're great tools, but require a pretty significant investment in time to get up and running.

You can also use [Telerik's Test Studio](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/) which makes it easier to quickly get good performance and load tests up and running. Please note I said "easier" and not "easy." Load and performance testing of websites takes anywhere from a moderate amount of work to "OMG! This is nuts!"

Disclaimer: I'm the director of engineering for Test Studio, so I'm a bit biased about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

For load testing you have to user load testing tool like `Jmeter or Loadrunner`.
Jmeter is an open source tool and Load runner is paid tool but both are user to find load of the website there is other tool also available in the marker which is used to find the load of a website and that tool is free for 1 month.
But you have to use tool to find load of a website